# Android Studio 0.8.0 - Unable to find explicit activity class

Tags: android

I've got a problem trying to do something in android studio and i'm not getting any progress.

When I try to call a the activity Menu from Main Activity Android studio give me this error message:

```
31490-31515/com.example.agr.companion E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-48434
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.agr.companion/android.view.Menu}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1556)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1431)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3561)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3529)
        at com.example.agr.companion.MyActivity$1.run(MyActivity.java:26)
```

This is my manifest:

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And this is how I try to start the new activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menu.class);
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

I'm very lost, I tried lots of things but I don't find anything helpful. I've made other projects in android studio that have the same code and it work. Recently I upgrade to android studio 0.8.0 and maybe something changes...

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Are they in the same package?

Comment: Yes, into: package com.example.agr.companion;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you try to start the [view.Menu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html) class as an activity, probably due to a false import. Take a look at the exception. It states com.example.agr.companion/**android.view.Menu**.

If you don't use a menu view in your activity, I would remove the false import at the top and add the correct one (of your com.example.agr.companion.Menu activity).

Another option is to rename your Menu.java activity to MenuActivity.java in order to avoid confusion.

The third option is to use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.example.agr.companion.Menu.class);
```

Comment: Yeah, the third option work. But I understand why android studio didn't recognize my class!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.agr.companion.MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I've tried this before asking here and doesn't work. Thank you! ^^